# How to access children of parent element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Naturally I tried:

```
function show() {
   this.parent.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

But debugger says that parent has no property children. What I'm doing wrong guys? And I can't use jQuery, I'm on hosted webserver.

Comment: I don't see "children" anywhere in the code, and you certainly can use jQuery regardless of your hosting.

Comment: By children of parent, do you mean siblings?

Comment: please, put the piece of html code you are trying to reach the children, to allow us help you.

Comment: Please give us some html and any additional javascript you're using. I can't really tell you anything with what you've given us.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be? Generally it's the `window`, which I really doubt you are meaning to use.

Comment: You're right, that was wrong 'this' I wanted to have :P

Comment: you want `parentNode` or `parentElement` -- `element.parent` would return undefined.

Comment: Neither would be what I wanted. Parent is defined.

Comment: Are you creating a 'parent' property? I'm not familiar with it being in the default spec.

Comment: parent is regular parameter of all node elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got hasty with this one. Parent was not node element, so it had no children. And 'this' had no parentNode property. What works is:

```
function show(node) {
    node.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

and

```
<a class="hider" onclick="show(this)">Test</a>
```

Naturally to other people indexes in childNodes list are irrelevant. But for me they work, but certainly it is not cleaver on nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parentNode for raw javascript, .parent() is jquery. So in your case:

```
function show() {
   this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: That's right, but that's not the root of my problem. I answered myself (got hasty with that question)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'this' seems to be the global scope. So 'this' points to window, which has no parent node.

Comment: True, I had posted answer to my own question cause I got hasty with asking one.